# ShaderMaterial on BufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader, buffer-geometry

How can I apply `ShaderMaterial` on a `BufferGeometry`? All the threejs examples and everything I could find on `BufferGeometry` use default materials (`MeshPhongMaterial` for example).

I have a working shader on `Geometry`, but when I convert it to `BufferGeometry` the shader no longer works. (I might have messed up the shader attributes count for example, absence of any explanation of `BufferGeometry` doesn't help).

Cound you please point me towards any working example or tell me what's the difference between using `ShaderMaterial` on `Geometry` and on `BufferGeometry`?

Comment: See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_custom_attributes_particles.html

Comment: Although not exactly what I had in mind, the link helped me. Thank you.